# always_ff order of commands?

Tags: verilog, clock, system-verilog

**Any help with this, there is no resources that discuss this specific problem.**

Given the following code:

```
1 always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
2     z1<=y1; y1<=x1;
3     z3=y3; y3=x3;
4 end
```

which claim is correct? (I wrote them to understand)

1. lines 1 & 2 are connected at the same time and only then we reach 3.
2. line 3 is connected first and then 1 & 2 are connected at the same time.
3. lines 1 & 2 & 3 are all connected at the same time (mostly incorrect).

Will the answer change if I change the code to:

```
1 always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
2     z3=y3; y3=x3;
3     z1<=y1; y1<=x1;
4 end
```

---

I read that inside `always_ff` the hardware is being made at the same time as long as we use <= (non blocking) but I didn't find **ANY** resource to match my specific case where I use both blocking and non blocking.

Comment: Hi daniel, you're asking a lot of question that you could better ask a systemverilog synthesizer, which in some cases will inform you that you can't do what you are trying to do.. Also, as pointed out at your previous question about `always_comb`, you need to stop thinking about things being "run".

Comment: Please don't tag irresponsibly. Repeatedly doing so can get you banned from the site.

Comment: yeah, this has nothing to do with [tag:risc-v] or [tag:logic-gates]

Comment: How have **you** tried to find the answer to this question? Do not assume that this is a free encyclopedia copied out to you on demand. Questions which show no research effort will be closed and the one who repeatedly asks such questions will get blocked from the site.

Comment: @ShashankVM Updated my question

Comment: @daniel, thank you for editing your question. You will find your answer in the SystemVerilog LRM, see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595. You will find the answer in the LRM. It is a pdf, so you can easily search for "blocking" in the pdf.

Comment: It needs student account @ShashankVM plus I know what blocking is I asked what if we combine both together what will happen first

Comment: what if line 2 is `z3=y3; y3=x3; z1<=y1; y1<=x1;`, and line 3 is `end`?

Comment: @daniel if you know what "blocking assignments" are, you're not showing that here.

Answer (score -1):

As a human who understands verilog, here's what I think your example describes:

clk is a clock signal that drives synchronous logic

z1 is the output of a D flip-flop whose value is 1 clock cycle delayed replica of y1

y1 is the output of a D flip-flop whose value is 1 clock cycle delayed replica of x1

So this always_ff block describes a two-stage shift register that takes x1 as the shift input, and outputs y1 (x1 delayed by 1 clk cycle) and z1 (x1 delayed by 2 clk cycles).

There are also some blocking assignment statments mixed in with the non-blocking assignment statements, which is very strange and unusual. Not sure why this was mixed together, but I'll try to interpret it as though it was properly coded as always continuous assignments at module level...

z3 is another name for the same signal as y3
and y3 is another name for the same signal as x3
so z3, y3, and x3 are always connected together asynchronously. It's not clear what is intended to drive the z3,y3,x3 output. That continuous assignment doesn't really belong in an always@clk type of block, because it's describing some hardware that is not synchronous with any clock. This code would make more sense if the z3,y3,x3 statement was an assign outside of the always block:

```
    // shift register:
    // input clock clk
    // serial input x1
    // output y1 is x1 delayed by 1 clk cycle
    // output z1 is x1 delayed by 2 clk cycles
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        z1<=y1; // doesn't matter what order these two statements appear
        y1<=x1; // as long as the non-blocking assignments are inside always@posedge clk
    end

    // assuming x3 is a wire source
    // z3 is another name for the same signal as y3
    assign z3 = y3;
    // y3 is another name for the same signal as x3
    assign y3 = x3;
```

There's an important point about verilog and VHDL, which are hardware description languages. On the surface, the code does look a lot like procedural computer programming source code, and for *simulation* it's often possible to interpret it that way. But the real purpose of HDL's is *synthesis*, and that's really really hard in general. Most synthesis tools work by matching up recognizable patterns, something like what I did above: "oh look, there's an always @ posedge clk with some blocking assignments, that must be a latch or a flip flop." If there's anything that doesn't match up with a recognizable pattern, the synthesis tool very likely won't succeed. So it's important to always keep in mind what kind of hardware you're trying to describe. Verilog/VHDL are really closer to circuit design than to computer programming. Often I have to actually draw a schematic on a whiteboard before I write my verilog code, and then afterwards I check the generated RTL to make sure that the synthesis tool didn't get confused and omit something important. Here's what your code look like drawn as an equivalent schematic, so you can see why it doesn't make sense to ask what order the statements happen:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSYEaD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi, It's not a mistake that I had both blocking and non blocking but It was made in purpose to understand what is being interested first, can you help me know which claim is correct 1,2 or 3?

Comment: No, none of those claims is correct... there is no concept of 'first', the entire hardware all exists at the same time after synthesis. The synchronous logic is implemented by the non-blocking assignments, there simply isn't any question of mixing blocking and non-blocking in synthesis. As a result, simulation also deliberately makes the order of operations indeterminate (in case of design errors such as expressed in your example question). The question is based on a false hypothesis that there is an order of execution, when there simply isn't.

Comment: Put another way: when we need things to happen in a certain order, we do that by implementing a *finite state machine*, because we can't enforce any order of operations in verilog or VHDL.